# Get data, process payment and then get it again

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've set up my IPN on PayPal and I get the transaction id, product name and all that but my question is how can I set up custom fields that I can retrieve after payment using the IPN?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called CUSTOM that you include in your button code or API calls.  Anything you pass here will come back in IPN as $_POST['custom'].  If you need multiple parameters you could store them there as an NVP string or however you want to pass them and then parse them back out within your IPN script.

Alternatively, you could save all your order data to your database prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  Then you can include your db record ID in the PayPal payment using the INVOICE parameter, which again, would come back in IPN as $_POST['invoice'].  With that you could pull the data back out of your DB based on the record ID and process it accordingly.